# PJax() not working in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have two modules. The one won't create traffic using Pjax(). This one with exact same code for Grid **will create traffic**. Any ideas, why?
Here is exactly same Gridcode for both modules:

```
    <?=
    Html::endForm();
    Pjax::begin();//this is ineffective! Why !!
    ?>

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <?=
            GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                'filterSelector' => '.choiceRadio',
                'id' => 'cb',
                'columns' => $gridColumn,
                'options' => [
                    'style' => 'overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;'
                ],
                'pjax' => true,
                'pjaxSettings' => [
                    'neverTimeout' => true,
                ],
                'panel' => [
                    "heading" => "<h3 class='panel-title'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-globe'></i> " . $this->title . "</h3>",
                    'type' => 'danger',
                    'after' => Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Reset Grid', ['/mail/mail-eingang/index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-warning', 'title' => 'Setzt die GridView zurück']),
                    'toggleDataOptions' => ['minCount' => 10],
                ],
                'toolbar' => [
                    '{export}',
                    '{toggleData}'
                ],
            ]);
            Pjax::end();
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by not working it still works if i run by copy pasting it as is

Comment: That means, that I will have traffic sending requests to searchmodel!! In the other modul  copy pasting it as is, I won't have any traffic!

Comment: var_dump( Pjax::begin() ) won't show any differences sending request to Searchmodel. So, Pjax::begin() is not working in this case!

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding your problem. What do you mean by saying **will create traffic**?

Comment: That means loading data by server! This should be avoided using AJAX!